# Page is shown on DOM but can't be crawled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I don't have a direct access to the code itself right now, But I've got some client whose website was developed in angularjs, and all the code gives an output on the DOM (I can see the pages with all the elements and everything is loaded just fine), but when I tried to make a crawling test via Google - it looked like the website wasn't scanned yet, even though it's been already a month.. and then I saw something weird - that when I 'view source' the pages themselves, all I get is this piece of code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="ahrefs-site-verification" content="xxxyyy">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.32f34f185b7564580e93.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.34e0ced836cdde276d53.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.700c13e3feb6da6eca5f.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.e89588fe3aa7c32000ef.js"></script></body>
<script src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js" async=""></script>
</html>
```

I guess the problem is happening in these lines -

```
 <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
```

Do you have at least any speculation why this might happen?

Comment: What you have pasted there is the entire html source of the page. The content you actually see will be generated by client-side Javascript (note the many scripts linked to at the bottom).

Comment: The reason is that you are creating the page through JavaScript that means nothing will be shown in the `view source` as JavaScript does not work on `view source` and maybe that's why Google not able to crawl your website.

Comment: `Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.` This message will only be shown when JavaScript is disabled in the browser and it will not create any issue and not prevent Google to crawl your site.

Comment: elements are available through the 'inspect element', but I was wondering if this 'enable javascript' message might affect the crawling from google's robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a SPA, SEO is not that straightforward. Google crawls your index.html which contains the app-root of your Angular app and my experience is that it will not execute the JS which contains your SPA routes. Your only options for optimizing SEO in SPA's is prerendering your routes, through an external service like [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) or create your own prerender or use a Server Side Rendering technology for your SPA.

Since you are using Angular you should take a look at [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

**edit**: if you don't want the complete hassle of prerendering all your routes but just want an acceptable result in Google for your index.html at least set a proper title tag `<title>Proper Title - Wonderful website</title>` and the meta description tag `<meta name="description" content="Description of max 160 chars">`

Answer (score 0):

**You might try Inspect Element instead of View Source**
I don't know whether the project has been deployed in dev mode or production mode but doing an Inspect element will help you to access the DOM elements.

[You can check this article to understand the difference between view source and Inspect Element](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/view-source-vs-inspect-element)

Comment: elements are available through the 'inspect element', but I was wondering if this 'enable javascript' message might affect the crawling from google's robot.

Comment: No that's not a concern. It is simply reading the <noscript> tag.  Since you are able to see the pages of the website without any issues that means your browser has javascript enabled already!